# df.replace not having any effect when trying to replace dates in pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, replace

I've been through the various comments on here about df.replace but I'm still not able to get it working.

Here is a snippet of my code:

```
# Name columns
df_yearly.columns = ['symbol', 'date', ' annuual % price change']

# Change date format to D/M/Y
df_yearly['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df_yearly['date'], format='%d/%m/%Y')
```

The df_yearly dataframe looks like this:

```
    | symbol |    date    |  annuual % price change 
 ---|--------|------------|------------------------- 
  0 | APX    | 12/31/2017 |                         
  1 | APX    | 12/31/2018 |            -0.502554278 
  2 | AURA   | 12/31/2018 |            -0.974450706 
  3 | BASH   | 12/31/2016 |            -0.998110828 
  4 | BASH   | 12/31/2017 |             8.989361702 
  5 | BASH   | 12/31/2018 |            -0.083599574 
  6 | BCC    | 12/31/2017 |             121718.9303 
  7 | BCC    | 12/31/2018 |            -0.998018734
```

I want to replace all dates of 12/31/2018 with 06/30/2018.  The next section of my code is:

```
# Replace 31-12-2018 with 30-06-2018 as this is final date in monthly DF
df_yearly_1 = df_yearly.date.replace('31-12-2018', '30-06-2018')
print(df_yearly_1)
```

But the output is still coming as:

```
   | 0 |  2017-12-31 
   | 1 |  2018-12-31 
   | 2 |  2018-12-31 
   | 3 |  2016-12-31 
   | 4 |  2017-12-31 
   | 5 |  2018-12-31
```

Is anyone able to help me with this?  I thought this might be related to me having the date format incorrect in my df.replace statement but I've tried to search and replace 12-31-2018 and it's still not doing anything.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Can you do `print(df_yearly.to_dict())` to reproduce the dataframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try '.astype(str).replace'

```
df.date.astype(str).replace('2016-12-31', '2018-06-31')
```